# "Access to Connection denied" linkedin-j android

Tags: android, linkedin-j

I'm using linkedin-j in my android app.By following library usage as mentioned in

https://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/wiki/OAuthFlow

https://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/wiki/GettingStarted

I'm able to get logged-in user details. But I'm having problem while getting Connections and Posting network updates.In myeclipse it showing an error Access to Connection denied.
Any one can help me how to get email too. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: i think you have to look in to this ---> http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-update-status-linked-in.html

Comment: that code is not working its giving an error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthConsumer" i have copied scribe-1.3.1.jar and linkedin-j-android.jar in libs file and buildpath too.

Comment: check BuildPath->Order and Export -> select All. clean & run...

Comment: Yeah its working ,we need to add signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar and other jar files which are given with linkedin-j.  How to get email?  How to send multiple permissions through scopeparams.

Comment: Thanks.. for send multiple & Email you have to check Linked-in API. i ll find it i ll get then post here...

Comment: i have gone through your code for update status as mentioned in http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-update-status-linked-in.html . Its not working. can u help me out please

Comment: have you used my all code?? and you have created app on linkedin?? which error you got? can you show me that errors?

Comment: Use socialAuth Android. You can easily post messages and do other stuff with linkedin. Minimal coding require. https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

Please check default scope in your linkedin app.